# scrapy: scraped data results to _sre.SRE_Match object at 0x044f6ee0

Tags: regex, scrapy

I tried using regex to get data from https://www.healthcaresource.com/lourdesnet/index.cfm?cJobId=404873&fuseaction=search.jobDetails&template=dsp_job_details.cfm

and the href gives me

```
javascript:openit('?fuseaction=apply.login&template=dsp_apply_login.cfm&cJobId=404873');toggleElement('applyLinks_1'); toggleElement('externalApplyConfirm_1');
```

I only wanted to get the

```
?fuseaction=apply.login&template=dsp_apply_login.cfm&cJobId=404873
```

my code is

```
link = infoer.select('@onclick').extract()[0]
item ["info"] = re.search("\'(\?[^\s]+)\&(cJobId\=\d+\')", link)
```

but it results to  _sre.SRE_Match object at 0x044f6ee0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `group()` method. Also, `'(.*?)'` expression looks more suiteable:

```
item ["info"] = re.search("'(.*?)'", link).group(1)
```